# Определение структур функций в классе

Tags: функции, классы, структуры, c++, visual-c++

Имеется некоторый класс с оочень большим количеством функций. Я решил как-то структурировать их, придать им осмысление и запихал их в структуры в public'е.

```
class something {
int fortyTwo;
public:
struct fold {
    void    fold1();
    void    fold2();

    void    fold3();
} fold;

struct take {
    void    take1();
    void    take2();
} take;
```

};

Как теперь позволить им управлять данными в материнском классе? Как их определять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про материнский класс вы правильно заметили. Вам стоит реализовать это через наследование (если вообще имеет смысл), а не городить адов ад такими велосипедами.

В С++ нет возможности обращаться к внешнему классу из вложенного (в отличие от Java, к примеру).